# Looping through all files in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have a two codes. I would like the second code to perform the first code on all files in a directory. The first code works like a charm and does exactly what I need it to, this is that:

```
Sub STATTRANSFER()
' Transfers all STATS lines
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "STATS"
Set f = Sheets(1)
Set e = Sheets("Stats")
Dim d
Dim j
Dim k
d = 1
j = 1
k = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(f.Range("A" & j))
    If f.Range("A" & j) = "STATS" Then
    e.Rows(d).Value = f.Rows(j).Value
    d = d + 1
    f.Rows(j).Delete
    Else
    j = j + 1
    End If
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The second code looks like this:

```
    Public Sub DataProcess()

Dim folderPath
Dim filename
Dim newfilename
Dim SavePath
Dim mySubFolder As Object
Dim mainFolder As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim OrigWB As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim name1 As String
Dim name2 As String

Set OrigWB = ThisWorkbook

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path


Set mainFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)


filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(filename) > 0
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
    Call STATTRANSFER

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    filename = Dir
Loop



For Each mySubFolder In mainFolder.SubFolders
    filename = Dir(mySubFolder.Path & "\*.csv*")
    Do While Len(filename) > 0
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(mySubFolder.Path & "\" & filename)
        Call STATTRANSFER

        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        filename = Dir
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

The second code does successfully loop through all of the folders and documents I want it to, however it performs my first code incorrectly. When I perform the first code on a sheet alone, it creates a new sheet called STATS then takes all lines from the first sheet that has the word STATS in column A and copies them to the new sheet, it then deletes the STATS lines out of the first sheet.

When I run it with the second code that goes through all the folders it doesn't work the same. I can see it create the sheet called STATS on my screen but then when it finishes and I open up on of the documents all the lines that have STATS in column A are on the first sheet, the STATS sheet is no longer there, and all the data that didn't have STATS in column A is gone. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the second macro with `F8`? It'll let you watch the macro move line by line, and you can help pin down *where* the macro takes a left turn.  I'm thinking (out loud) you may want to pass the workbook into the first macro, so it knows to use the specific workbook?

Comment: Are you trying to open a workbook in the folders then run STATTRANSFER?  If so you'll need to reference WB in it.

Comment: @BruceWayne   Stepping through with F8 wont do anything I believe because the code runs fine with no errors

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I Believe so but I guess I don't know what other option there is nor do I know exactly hat you mean to fix it.

Comment: I know it runs fine without error, but it looks like it's not doing it correctly.  Stepping through it will help you determine where it goes wrong.  But yeah, it won't correct anything, but will help narrow where the macro stops doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your first sub as it is, replace your second sub with this:

```
Sub MM()

Dim file     As Variant
Dim files    As Variant
Dim WB       As Excel.Workbook

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

For Each file In files
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(file)
    STATTRANSFER
    WB.Close True
    Set WB = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this Save the Workbook as it closes?  and Thanks, I will try it

Comment: Yes, `WB.Close True` will do that - I've just not explicitly stated the `SaveChanges` argument but it doesn't make a difference in this particular case, it will still work

Comment: But wont the 1st sub operate on ActiveWorkbook/Thisworkbook or WB.  I think it would be safe to have WB as an argument in function 1 and then reference it, so STATTRANSFER(wbToOperateOn as excel.workbook)

Comment: This Yields the exact same problem, but If i run the STATTRANSFER macro alone on a document it works just fine. So confused

Comment: @Nathan_Sav when the sub uses `Workbooks.Open(file)` <-- that _becomes_ the activeworkbook

Comment: @R.Green there is obviously something different in the workbook you're testing the first sub on. Both subs use the ActiveWorkbook so you need to set a breakpoint on the `Workbooks.Open(file)` command and then step through to see what the difference is and where the code is falling over

Comment: I will answer the question one moment

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but if the user clicks the opening workbook half way through (live i've done in the past, a habit of spinning my pen, or leaning on the mouse) then its best practice to ref the open workbook.  Is all i am saying... :)

Answer (score 0):

just as an remark: your code only runs thru the first level of sub folders. If you want to go thru all sub level folders, you have to use a recursive method like:

```
Private Sub test()
    readFileSystem ("C:\Temp\")
End Sub

Private Sub readFileSystem(ByVal pFolder As String)
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object

    ' create FSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' get start folder
    Set oFolder = oFSO.getFolder(pFolder)

    ' list folder content
    listFolderContent oFolder

    ' destroy FSO
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub listFolderContent(ByVal pFolder As Object)
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object

    ' go thru all sub folders
    For Each oFolder In pFolder.SubFolders
        Debug.Print oFolder.Path
        ' do the recursion to list sub folder content
        listFolderContent oFolder
    Next

    ' list all files in that directory
    For Each oFile In pFolder.Files
        Debug.Print oFile.Path
    Next

    ' destroy all objects
    Set pFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

this is just an example and you have to call your first procedure of course still correct. So I would suggest to add a parameter to the first procedure where you can pass the workbook.

and BTW: always delcare your variables with datatype. Dim j will declare a VARIANT variable and not a Interger as you might want to have.

Answer (score 0):

You see all STATS in the first sheet because you added an extra sheet to a CSV file and saved it. By definition, CSV file only saves and shows 1 sheet.
This modification to your code could solve your problem, as it calls itself to go through subfolders.
Try it.
Include your STATTRANSFER sub.

```
Public Sub DataProcess()

thisPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
process_folders (thisPath)

End Sub

Sub process_folders(thisPath)

Dim folderPath
Dim filename
Dim newfilename
Dim SavePath
Dim mySubFolder As Object
Dim mainFolder As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim OrigWB As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim name1 As String
Dim name2 As String

Set OrigWB = ThisWorkbook

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set mainFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
filename = Dir(folderPath & "\*.csv")

Do While Len(filename) > 0
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & filename)
    Call STATTRANSFER

    'save file as Excel file !!!
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    filename:=(folderPath & "\" & filename), _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
    CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

    filename = Dir

Loop

    'now with each subfolder
    For Each subfolder In mainFolder.SubFolders
        process_folders (subfolder)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you can only save a .csv with one sheet on it. Now the code looks like this.

```
Sub NewDataProcess()

Dim file     As Variant
Dim files    As Variant
Dim wb       As Excel.Workbook

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

For Each file In files
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)
    Call STATTRANSFER(wb)
    newfilename = Replace(file, ".csv", ".xlsm")
    wb.SaveAs filename:=newfilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wb = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Now I need a way to delete the old files if someone can help with that.  I dont want the CSV file at all anymore

Comment: Sorry had to format the code, so does anyone know how to delete workbooks in the folder?